# Mercurial: How can a user clone another user's repository on Windows?

Tags: windows, mercurial

I have two users A and B on a Windows 7 machine. A has a Mercurial repository named Foo in a directory where both A and B have read-write access. When B tries to clone this repository he gets this error:

```
D:\Code>hg clone Foo FooClone
abort: D:\Code\Foo\.hg\requires: Access is denied
```

What is the cause of this error? How does a user clone a repository created by another user on the same Windows 7 machine?

Comment: The directories have read-write access, but you may want to check the read-write access of the files contained within the .hg directory, perhaps?

Comment: icabod: Yes, B does not seem to have access to the files inside .hg. So, 2 users on a computer cannot clone or share their repositories in some way? That seems strange!

Comment: There should be no problem cloning someone's repo, so unless there's some internal Mercurial bug I would guess this is down to Win7 permissions now flowing down to newly-created files in that directory. I don't know a huge amount about Win7 permissions, but it could be worth looking on superuser.com.

Comment: I meant "not flowing down..." of course.

Comment: Icabod: Turns out that B had only read access to those files. The clone worked once I logged in as A and gave full control permissions to B.

Comment: Ashwin: I find it odd that B would need anything more than Read access to the files, but there you go - at least you have it working now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might decide this is too restrictive compared to cloning directly from the file system, but you could set up a web server on the machine, and [have each user set up a directory containing repositories to serve over HTTP](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories). Once the infrastructure is up and running, it should be no more difficult to use this setup day to day, and you won't run into file system permission problems.

Answer (score 0):

icabod may be right about permissions, but this may instead have to do with ownership. User A may own those files, even though they're shared with B.

Try running the commandline console as Administrator.